# $\frac{2(1+4a^2)}{(12x-1)^3}\leqslant \frac{(1-a)^4}{[12x-(1-a)^2]^3}+\frac{(1+a)^4}{[12x-(1+a)^2]^3}$ for $0\leq a<\frac13$ and $x>\frac{(1+a)^2}8$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, recreational-mathematics, computational-mathematics

> How to prove the inequality below？
> $$\frac{2(1+4a^2)}{(12x-1)^3}\leqslant \frac{(1-a)^4}{[12x-(1-a)^2]^3}+\frac{(1+a)^4}{[12x-(1+a)^2]^3}$$ holds for all $0\leqslant a<\frac{1}{3}$ and $x>\frac{(1+a)^2}{8}$.

This question has been bothering me for a while. Using numerical experiment, we found that $\frac{(1-a)^4}{[12x-(1-a)^2]^3}+\frac{(1+a)^4}{[12x-(1+a)^2]^3}-\frac{2(1+4a^2)}{(12x-1)^3}$ is strictly increasing in $x\in (\frac{(1+a)^2}{8},+\infty)$, but it seems not easy to prove it.

[image]

Thanks to everyone!

[image]

Comment: Do you need to find $x$? Or $a$? Or prove that it's true for all $a$ and $x$ with the given conditions? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried our best to prove that this inequality holds for all $0\leqslant a<\frac{1}{3}$ and $x>\frac{(1+a)^2}{8}$.. Thank you !

Comment: Please include what you've tried and where you got stuck, so that people don't waste time explaining things you already understand or duplicating your effort. You might also provide additional context such as the source of the exercise, to give a sense of the level of complexity a solution might involve. (Be sure to include all context and clarifications in the body of the question itself. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden, moved, or deleted.)

Comment: We have used all inequality formulas, including convexity. Using numerical experiment, we found that $\frac{(1-a)^4}{[12x-(1-a)^2]^3}+\frac{(1+a)^4}{[12x-(1+a)^2]^3}-\frac{2(1+4a^2)}{(12x-1)^2}>0$ is strictly increasing in $x\in (\frac{(1+a)^2}{8},+\infty)$, but it seems not easy to prove it.

Comment: We tried to compare two profit functions. Thus, the inequality above may be inevitable.

Comment: Can you double check your inequality? When $a=0.1$, the solutions are according to WA $0.0675<x<0.0770771$ and $0.100833<x<0.197691$ which looks nothing like what you're suggesting the solution set should be.

Comment: We require $x>\frac{(1+a)^2}{8}$. Thus, when $a=0.1$,  $x$ must be higher than 0.1525, i.e., $x>0.1525$. When $a=0.1$ and $x=0.16$, it is seen that the left side is 2.671, whereas the right side is 4.5704. The inequality still holds. Thank you!

Comment: @yuemingshi Should it be $\frac{2(1+4a^2)}{(12x-1)^3} \le \frac{(1-a)^4}{[12x-(1-a)^2]^3}+\frac{(1+a)^4}{[12x-(1+a)^2]^3}$? When $a = 0$, we have $LHS = RHS$.

Comment: Yes! I ignored it and have revised it !

Comment: @yuemingshi You forgot to revise some places. I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$(1 - a)^4 + (1 + a)^4 - 2(1 + 4a^2) = 4a^2 + 2a^4 \ge 0.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{(1 - a)^4 + (1 + a)^4}{(12x-1)^3}\leqslant \frac{(1-a)^4}{[12x-(1-a)^2]^3}+\frac{(1+a)^4}{[12x-(1+a)^2]^3}$$
or
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{1}{(12x - 1)^3}\\
 \le\,& \frac{(1 - a)^4}{(1 - a)^4 + (1 + a)^4}\cdot \frac{1}{[12x - (1 - a)^2]^3}
 + \frac{(1 + a)^4}{(1 - a)^4 + (1 + a)^4}\cdot \frac{1}{[12x - (1 + a)^2]^3}.
\end{align*}

Note that $u\mapsto \frac{1}{(12x - u)^3}$ is convex on $0 \le u \le 8x$.
By Jensen's inequality,
we have
$$\mathrm{RHS} \ge \frac{1}{(12x - A)^3} \ge \frac{1}{(12x - 1)^3}$$
where
$$A = \frac{(1 - a)^4}{(1 - a)^4 + (1 + a)^4}(1 - a)^2
+ \frac{(1 + a)^4}{(1 - a)^4 + (1 + a)^4}(1 + a)^2,$$
and we have used
$$A - 1 = \frac{(1 - a)^6 + (1 + a)^6 - (1 - a)^4 - (1 + a)^4}{(1 - a)^4 + (1 + a)^4} \ge 0.$$

We are done.

Comment: Very very right! Perfectly!

Comment: Very very right! Perfectly! I have proven this inequality 3 days! You perfectly resolved it!